# DropDownList and Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, drop-down-menu

I develop address control, which contains 2 DropDownLists (for cities and countries) and several TextBoxes. The second DropDownList DataSource depends on the first DropDownList DataSource.

```
<fieldset>
 <legend><%=Title%></legend>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <label for="<%=ddlCountry.ClientID %>">Country</label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCountry" 
              DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" 
              DataSource="<%#Facade.Addresses.GetCountries() %>"
              AutoPostBack="true" 
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="<%=ddlCity.ClientID %>">City</label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCity" 
                DataTextField="Name"   DataValueField="Name" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div>
    <label for="<%=txtStreet.ClientID %>">Street</label>
    <uc:TextBox ID="txtStreet" Text="<%#Address.Street %>" runat="server" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="<%=txtBlock.ClientID %>">Block</label>
    <uc:TextBox ID="txtBlock" Text="<%#Address.Block %>" runat="server" />
</div>
<div>
</fieldset>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    ddlCountry.DataBind();
     if (!IsPostBack)
       {
         ddlCity.DataSource = Facade.Addresses.GetCities(countryId);
         ddlCity.DataBind();
      }

}

protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     ddlCity.DataSource = Facade.Addresses.GetCities(countryId);
     ddlCity.DataBind();
 }
```

It works good. But if other control on the page causes PostBack, when the SelectedValue in ddlCity sets to the first (default) value.

How do I avoid it?

Comment: Fahad has the solution.  The recommendation from naveen is just to conform to standards, although you only need on !IsPostback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the code on `Page_Init` to `Page_Load` and put it inside `!IsPostBack`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlCountry.DataBind();
        ddlCity.DataSource = Facade.Addresses.GetCities(countryId);
        ddlCity.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you check for "IsPostBack" twice?

Answer (score 0):

put ddlCountry.DataBind(); inside if condition